# Insert Attachments by content type via Apex

Tags: apex, attachment

Currently when we insert an attachment via Apex code it automatically converts in to attachment type regardless of the file type. For example when we insert a Jpg file, it converts to plain attachment. This leads downloading the image instead of open it as pop-up on UI. Here's the code,

```
Attachment myAttachment  = new Attachment();
myAttachment.Body = fileBody;
myAttachment.Name = fileName;
myAttachment.ParentId = aLead.id;
myAttachment.contentType = contentType;

insert myAttachment;
```

Any lead to resolve this?

Comment: Does the file has right extension after insert? If yes then it should work fine.

Comment: Yup. It has the right extension